# CSS for only 1 part of HTML

Tags: html, css

How do get CSS to only affect the first list (menu items) only, and not the second list? Please help. I've been at this all day. If you could, copy/paste the complete code back in your response. VERY appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-    type">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
  ul {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
  ul li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;border:1px solid #000}
  li ul {display: none;}
  ul li a {display: block;background: #000;padding: 5px 10px 5px     10px;text-decoration: none;
           white-space: nowrap;color: #fff;}
  ul li a:hover {background: #f00;}
  li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
  li:hover li {float: none;}
  li:hover a {background: #f00;}
  li:hover li a:hover {background: #000;}
  #drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}
</style></head>
  <body>
    <ul id="drop-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Content Management</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Joomla</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Drupal</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Concrete 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">General Inquiries</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ask me a Question</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <ol>
      <li style="list-style-type: disc;"><a href="www.google.com">link1</a></li>
      <li style="list-style-type: disc;"><a    href="www.yahoo.com">link2</a></li>
    </ol>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I would say prefix all your rules with `#drop-nav`, but you're already doing that with your last rule.  Does that not work for you?  Is there some other issue you're running into?

Comment: Yes. The CSS is designed to change the link to red when you hover over it. Just want that to happen with the menu list links. Not the Google/Yahoo list links.

Comment: I understand that I can surround the menu code with DIV. But how is that done? And how would that link back to CSS code?

Comment: @MapMan You add `<div>` and `</div>` to the code before and after your opening and closing unordered list tags, respectively. The advice Paulie gave you is useful: check out a site like the Mozilla Developer Network to learn more about the fundamentals of HTML and CSS

Comment: Yes, I was too quick with the sarcasm remark. Been reading all day and its not sinking in. I got the DIV surrounding concept, that's conceptual and I understand that. So I could do <div class="intro"> and then </div>. But where/how do I do a " .menu " in the CSS portion? That's perplexing me.

Comment: meant to say <div class="menu"> and </div> and .menu

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're asking. `.menu` would be a CSS selector that goes in a CSS file, or in the `<style>` tag inside your document's `<head>`.

Comment: IN the style tag? how exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I've only changed two pieces of your code. You will see where I reference the class `.menu` in your CSS and where i'm using the `class="menu"` on your drop-nav list.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-    type">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
   ul {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
   ul li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;border:1px solid #000}
   li ul {display: none;}
   ul li a {display: block;background: #000;padding: 5px 10px 5px     10px;text-decoration: none;
      white-space: nowrap;color: #fff;}
   ul li a:hover {background: #f00;}
   li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
   li:hover li {float: none;}
   .menu li:hover a {background: #f00;}
   li:hover li a:hover {background: #000;}
   #drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}
 </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="drop-nav" class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Content Management</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Joomla</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Drupal</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Concrete 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">General Inquiries</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ask me a Question</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <ol>
      <li style="list-style-type: disc;"><a href="www.google.com">link1</a></li>
      <li style="list-style-type: disc;"><a    href="www.yahoo.com">link2</a></li>
    </ol>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: arman, this works too! Man, I tell you. There is a world of stuff out there I have no idea about. I have a damn PhD (in my field) and I'm humbled with you all, how quickly you were able to zone in on my issue.

Comment: No problem, we've all been there. I mostly wanted to demonstrate for you the relationship between the CSS class and the HTML class.
In my opinion, the absolute best resource for learning proper HTML/CSS very quickly is Codecademy. It's interactive, so you will "learn by example" which will help retain the concepts behind it all: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/web

Answer (score 0):

> The CSS is designed to change the link to red when you hover over it. Just want that to happen with the menu list links. Not the Google/Yahoo list links.

You have this

```
li:hover a {background: #f00;}
```

Change that to

```
ul li:hover a {background: #f00;}
```

This will differentiate it from the `ol` links

Comment: sarcasm is not help. Grow up.

Comment: Paulie D, you did it. That works! I don't know who or where you are, but if you were here, I'd take you out for a steak dinner.

Comment: So sorry about the sacrasm remark. I read your response too fast and read it as if you were writting me off. Thank you sincerely. All of you!

Answer (score 0):

You can give html elements ids or classes, ids are for unique elements and classes are for more common elements.

In the Css you can give a class a set styling. For you problem follow the ideas I present below:

First line html elements give a class

```
<ul href='#' class="headingItem></ul>
```

To style those elements with that class (Css):

```
.headingItem{
    Colour:blue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CSS class. You can target only the ` elements with that class:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-    type">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
  ul.menu {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
  ul.menu li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;border:1px solid #000}
  li ul {display: none;}
  ul.menu li a {display: block;background: #000;padding: 5px 10px 5px     10px;text-decoration: none;
           white-space: nowrap;color: #fff;}
  ul.menu li a:hover {background: #f00;}
  li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
  li:hover li {float: none;}
  li:hover a {background: #f00;}
  li:hover li a:hover {background: #000;}
  #drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}
</style></head>
  <body>
    <ul id="drop-nav">
      <li class="menu"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
      <li class="menu"><a href="#">Web Design</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu"><a href="#">Content Management</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Joomla</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Drupal</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">WordPress</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Concrete 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu"><a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">General Inquiries</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ask me a Question</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <ol>
      <li style="list-style-type: disc;"><a href="www.google.com">link1</a></li>
      <li style="list-style-type: disc;"><a    href="www.yahoo.com">link2</a></li>
    </ol>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: This destroys the menu formatting. And stills makes everything hover red.

Answer (score 0):

Change `li:hover a {background: #f00;}` to `ul > li:hover a {background: #f00;}`.
`>` means `Child`, or `sub item`. This will make only your navigation links (or other links in an `ul > li` tag) be red when hovered. Or try this: `#drop-nav > ul > li:hover a {background: #f00;}` for only your navigator.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should name your first ul with class or id and then use this form of CSS selecor ul.class > li. This is the only way to get to the first level of children.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 14px;
            }

            ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                padding: 0;
            }

            ul.menu > li {
                background-color: red;
                float: left;
                position: relative;
                width: 100px;
                margin-right: 5px;
                padding: 5px;
            }

            ul.menu > li ul {
                position: absolute;
                top: 26px;
                left: 0px;
                display: none;
            }

            ul.menu > li:hover ul {
                display: block;
            }

            ul.menu > li ul li {
                width: 100px;
                padding: 5px;
                background-color: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>First
                <ul>
                    <li>Sub-First</li>
                    <li>Sub-Second</li>
                    <li>Sub-Third</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Second</li>
            <li>Third
                <ul>
                    <li>Sub-First</li>
                    <li>Sub-Second</li>
                    <li>Sub-Third</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this gave funky results. But I got it. Thanks Sasha